# templating using handlebars with nodejs to include layout

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

app.js

```
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use('/catalog', require('./routes/catalog'));
```

so in my routes folder I have a folder call catalog then within it I have catalog.js.

In catalog.js I do

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = module.exports = express.Router();
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('catalog/index');
});
```

It worked fine when I go to `http://localhost:3000/catalog` but it excluded from the layout when I try to run `http://localhost:3000/catalog/` Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an npm package (connect-slashes) which installs some middleware which will add a slash on urls without one. This process is called URL canonicalisation.

This is better because you won't display similar content for 'catalog' and 'catalog/' urls which would be bad for SEO (duplicate content penalties).

Package details here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-slashes

From the command line:

```
npm install connect-slashes --save
```

Comment: I know --save but what is --save-deps?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of --save-dev but --save is probably best. updated answer.